# PHP output an Array

Tags: php

i`ve an array with more arrays inside.
But how can i get a specific value from it ?

For example how can i output the first name "John" ?

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
foreach($arr as $result) {
    echo $result['CLIENTS']['FIRSTNAME'];
}
```

This is the < pre> output of the array

```
Array
(
[WHMCSAPI] => Array
    (
        [ACTION] => getclients
        [RESULT] => success
        [TOTALRESULTS] => 12
        [STARTNUMBER] => 0
        [NUMRETURNED] => 12
        [CLIENTS] => Array
            (
                [CLIENT] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 14
                        [FIRSTNAME] => John
                        [LASTNAME] => Doe
                        [COMPANYNAME] => Muster Company
                        [EMAIL] => info@mustermann.de
                        [DATECREATED] => 2014-04-13
                        [GROUPID] => 0
                        [STATUS] => Active
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. You're supposed to do `$result['WHMCSAPI']['CLIENTS']['CLIENT']['FIRSTNAME']`. If you want to iterate the whole array you should use more foreach loops,the first only only loops through ACTION, RESULT, TOTALRESULTS, NUMRETURNED and, finally, CLIENTS. perhaps, to loop, check the prototype "is_array($element)" from the documentation to check if the element you're looking at is an array or not :)

Comment: As they say "If everything else fail, Read The F***ing Manual".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers & comments are almost right, but they didn't notice that you're iterating over the array.

Here's your code:

```
foreach($arr as $result) {
    echo $result['CLIENTS']['FIRSTNAME'];
}
```

**Inside the loop** (this is important), $result is equal to:

```
Array
    (
        [ACTION] => getclients
        [RESULT] => success
        [TOTALRESULTS] => 12
        [STARTNUMBER] => 0
        [NUMRETURNED] => 12
        [CLIENTS] => Array
            (
                [CLIENT] => Array
                    (
...
```

So to access the client name *inside the loop*, use this:

```
$firstname = $result["CLIENTS"]["CLIENT"]["FIRSTNAME"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple levels of the array. Try `$result['WHMCSAPI']['CLIENTS']['CLIENT']['FIRSTNAME']`.

Comment: I get also no result with this code :(

    foreach($arr as $result) {
    echo $result['WHMCSAPI']['CLIENTS']['CLIENT']['FIRSTNAME'];
}

Comment: I apologize, I misunderstood. Get rid of the WHMCSAPI part. So just `$result['CLIENTS']['CLIENT']['FIRSTNAME']`.